# Saving XML files in DataSet array and System.NullReferenceException occurs when selecting more than one XML file

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, dataset

I made a code where the I selected several XML files and save them on a DataSet array. So if I selected 5 XMl files, the DataSet array size is 5 (0-4), the tables in the dataset is filled with the XML nodes and subnodes

The first part of the code shows the way I saved the XML data into the DataSet array

Here is part of the code

```
public partial Form1:Form
{
    XmlReader xmlFile;

    DataSet[] XMlTable;

    string[] FileNames;
    string[] File;
```

.
.
.

```
private void Open_File_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
OpenFileDialog openXmlFile = new OpenFileDialog();
//Multiselect allows openfiledialog to select multiple files
openXmlFile.Multiselect = true;
openXmlFile.Filter = "XML Files |*.xml";
openXmlFile.Title = "Select XML Files";

        int size;
        dataGridView1.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top);

        try
        {
            if (openXmlFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (!string.Equals(Path.GetExtension(openXmlFile.FileName), ".xml", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    //invalid file type selected; display an error
                    MessageBox.Show("The selected file is not supported by this application. You must select an XML file.", "Invalid File Type", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }

                else
                {
                    //Find a way to show the selected file names only - right now it shows the whole address of the files
                    this.textBox1.Text = openXmlFile.FileName;

                    FileNames = openXmlFile.FileNames;
                    File = openXmlFile.SafeFileNames;
                    size = FileNames.Length;

                    for (int FileNumber = 0; FileNumber < FileNames.Length; FileNumber++)
                    {
                        //Deletes the node ICAD from XML file, if the ICAD node is present in an XML file and is not remove then the Datagridview will only show one column with the Icad Version

                        xmldoc.Load(FileNames[FileNumber]);
                        XmlNode nodeToDelete = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/conveyors/ICAD");

                        if (nodeToDelete != null)
                        {
                            nodeToDelete.ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodeToDelete);
                            xmldoc.Save(FileNames[FileNumber]);
                        }  //node does not exists

                        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
                        settings.IgnoreWhitespace = false;

                        xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(FileNames[FileNumber], settings);

                        XMlTable = new DataSet[size];
                        XMlTable[FileNumber] = new DataSet();
                        XMlTable[FileNumber].ReadXml(xmlFile);

                        xmlFile.Close();
                        Build_Manifest.Enabled = true;
                        Show_Table.Enabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
        }
    }
```

The code below is where the System.NullReferencesException error occurs and it only happens when I select more than one XML file

```
private void test1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Shows how big is the size of the Dataset array - it should be the same as the amount of selected files (5 files selected then array size = 5 (0-4)
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(string.Format("Size of Array ={0}", XMlTable.Length)));

        for (int test1 = 0; test1 < XMlTable.Length; test1++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(string.Format("Tables used = {0}",XMlTable[test1].Tables.Count)));
            MessageBox.Show(XMlTable[test1].Tables[0].TableName);
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is that you re-initialize `XMlTable` every iteration.
Thus, only the last dataset in the array is actually present. The rest are nulls.
Move the `XMlTable = new DataSet[size];` before the loop.